# WaitForExit() activates on UAC or Security Warning

Tags: c#, process.start, waitforexit

I'm fairly new to c# and this forum in general but as far as I'm concerned, I haven't seen any question like mine that will solve my problem.

I'm calling the method `Process.WaitForExit()` to wait until an installation file finishes to install. However, the method seems to consider the UAC as the 'process' and activates after I click OK on the UAC. Is there a better way to wait for an installation process to finish before the code proceeds? Or am I doing it wrong? Disabling the UAC manually (if that's possible) is a no go unless it's done programmatically as well.

Here's the part of the code:

Edit: proper calling of process

```
Process netInstall = Process.Start(filePath + "\\Installer.exe");
netInstall.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine("Installation Finished!");
```

Edit 2: Would it help if I say I'm installing MySQL Server 5.6? It seems that, besides the Security Warning, it pops up and close some windows before it starts too. Regards.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you saying you are capturing the UAC instead of your launched executable in the `netInstall` process?

Comment: I need to wait until the `netInstall` (which is an installer exe) to finish installing before proceeding to the `WriteLine` part of the code. But somehow, after I click OK on the UAC of the installer and the UAC window closes, it proceeds to the `WriteLine`. Thanks for the quick reply by the way. :)

Comment: you do realize that you aren't starting the installer in the `netInstall`'s instance space, but rather statically?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I've changed it like BayStallion's answer below but it still doesn't cover my main concern. The `WaitForExit()` still activates after I've closed some initial windows from the installer (UAC, Security Warning). I need it to finish the installation proper before proceeding. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code is not correct. You create an instance of the Process class, but then you call the static method Process.Start, which creates a new instance of Process.

Your code should look like this:

```
Process netInstall = Process.Start(filePath + "\\Installer.exe");
netInstall.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine("Installation Finished!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it still doesn't address my main concern about the `WaitForExit()` activating before the installer proper finishes. I'll update the main thread with that code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run your your application with elevated privileges:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator">
```

Also consider BasyStallion answer and correctly start netInstall

Comment: I have already elevated the privilege. I still have the Security Warning popping up and when I close it, it still activates the `WaitForExit()`.